# Get most recently occurring Wednesday?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

How would I get the most recently occurring Wednesday, using Ruby (and Rails, if there's a pertinent helper method)?

Ultimately need the actual date (5/1/2013).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works in Ruby:

```
require 'date'

def last_wednesday(date)
  date - (date.wday - 3) % 7
end

last_wednesday(Date.today)
# => #<Date: 2013-05-01 ((2456414j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

In Rails there's [`beginning_of_week`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#method-i-beginning_of_week):

```
Date.today.beginning_of_week(:wednesday)
# => Wed, 01 May 2013
```

Comment: `beginning_of_week` is a really interesting/concise way to solve this. Great idea!

Answer (score 8):

```
time = Time.now
days_to_go_back = (time.wday + 4) % 7
last_wed = days_to_go_back.days.ago
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are okay with using another gem, I recommend [Chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic).

With it, you can get last Wednesday by doing:

```
Chronic.parse('last Wednesday')
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way (to me) is:

```
require 'date'
date = Date.today
date -= 1 until date.wednesday?
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straightforward with [`Date`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html):

```
require 'date'
today = DateTime.now.to_date
last_wednesday = today.downto(today - 6).select { |d| d.wednesday? }
```

You can even get the last weekday of your choice like this (here without error handling):

```
def last_weekday(weekday)
  today = Time.now.to_date
  today.downto(today-6).select do |d|
    d.send((weekday.to_s + "?").to_sym)
  end
end
```